# How to force render in Angular for same input?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an issue where I have an input from a parent component like so

Parent HTML

```
<div>
  <child [childProperty]="parentProperty"</child>
</div>
```

And I have a setter so that the child calls a method whenever there is an input or the string "parentProperty" is populated with input.

Child TS:

```
private _childProperty: string;

@Input()
  set childProperty(value: string) {
    this._childProperty = value;
    this.doSomethingWithProperty();
  }
```

This works well but if the user inputs the same value, angular does not run the setter (I think because it doesn't detect a change?). I need to call "doSomethingWithProperty" even if the input is the same. What is the correct way to do this?

EDIT:
To anyone having a similar issue, I ended up just wrapping the string in an object creating a new reference. Not sure if this is the best way to solve this but it works.

Comment: You're right, both `@Input()` and `ngOnChanges` will only work if the value has actually changed during angulars change detection cycle. Can you elaborate on your use case a bit more? A shared service may provide the cleanest solution but not sure if it applies to your case.

Comment: @MikeS. I basically have a validation check in my child component and needs to run every time there is an input.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that manually from parent component:

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;

onInputChange(){
  this.child.doSomethingWithProperty();
}
```

This way no matter what the change is if it's detectable by the parent component you can run a function from child component

Answer (score 0):

You can make it through the clonation:

For instance: if you want the component detects the change all time, you should clone the object (the input) in the assignation:

```
this.childProperty = Object.assign({}, currentObject);
```

Regards.